# what are the differences between MediaSessionCompat and MediaSession in Android? And why do both androidx.media2 and androidx.media exist?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack

I've started new Android app project with Kotlin. My gradle configs for the SDK are `compileSdkVersion` 29 and `buildToolsVersion` "29.0.1"

I tried to make a feature which is a remapping button for bluetooth earphones. So I found that I have to handle `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`.

It looks like [MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/media2/session/MediaSession.html) is later than [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html). But I don't know what I should use.

About androidx. I wonder why they divided the package like `androidx.media` and `androidx.media2`?

Answer (score 5):

**I found it.**

> assuming you are using at least API level 28 SDK version with kotlin.

According to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview#compat-library MediaSessionCompat is a backport for supporting earlier than Android 4.1 (API level 16) and when android 5.0 released [MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html) came out.

AndroidX is the next library of [android  support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index). It needs Android 9.0 (API level 28).

In androidx, The package androidx.media is for supporting compabilities and package androidx.media2 is a next version of android.media.* which added API level 21. For example [MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/media2/session/MediaSession.html)

So If you want to use some classes in android.support.v4.media.session package which is media-compat library. You should add `implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'` in your `build.gradle`